Why are the objects overlapping footer when the height is smaller? CSS issue
I'm having a problem with div elements in HTML and CSS and it's a problem relating to the responsiveness of the code on smaller screens.
The page has the main content that is fixed to the top (all okay with it), it has a place where icons of some programming knowledge are, a place where projects cases/link for modals are (about six, which are structured to be aligned 3/3 or 2/2/2 or 1/1/1/1/1/1 as the screen demands) and the footer.
The issue is that everything aligns well in screens with smaller heights, but the project cases always overlap the footer.
There is a screenshot attached to this question showing what I'm trying to explain.
I will show the code in html and after the css for it:
Here are the divs in html:


  body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 420vh;
  background-color: rgb(15, 16, 43);
  /* Background color */
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: 700;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
}


/* PROJECT DIV FOR WIDTH =>768px WORKS WELL*/

.skills-projects {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Centraliza a div */
  padding: 40px 20px;
  /* Ajuste o padding lateral para 20px */
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 1200px;
  /* Define uma largura máxima */
  margin: 0;
  /* Remove margens */
  background-color: white;
  /* Fundo branco para a seção */
  padding: 40px 40px;
  /* Espaçamento interno */
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  /* Sombra para profundidade */
  border-radius: 8px;
  /* Cantos arredondados */
}

.portfolio-container {
  display: flex;
  /* Layout flexível */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* Permite quebra de linha */
  justify-content: center;
  /* Centraliza os projetos */
  gap: 15px;
  /* Espaço entre os projetos */
  margin-bottom: 300px;
  /* Espaço abaixo da seção de projetos */
}

.title-portfolio-container {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: 130px;
  color: #2c3e50;
  text-align: center;
  /* Center align the portfolio title */
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  /* Increased space below the title */
}

.project {
  width: 100%;
  /* Largura total para responsividade */
  max-width: 300px;
  /* Largura máxima para cada projeto */
  height: 200px;
  /* Altura fixa para uniformidade */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Oculta o excesso */
  border-radius: 8px;
  /* Cantos arredondados */
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  /* Sombra sutil */
  transition: transform 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  /* Efeito de transição */
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Remove sublinhado */
  color: inherit;
  /* Herda a cor do pai */
  position: relative;
  /* Posicionamento relativo para sobreposição */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* Estilos para telas com largura máxima de 768px */
  /* Corpo e HTML */
  body,
  html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /* Evita rolagem horizontal */
    height: 100%;
    /* aumentei o tamanho assim cabe mais coisa*/
  }
  body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 400vh;
    /* Garante que o corpo da página ocupe pelo menos 100% da altura da viewport */
    margin: 0;
  }
  .portfolio-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 15px;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 160px);
    /* Ajuste a altura mínima para evitar sobreposição */
    margin-bottom: 300px;
  }
  .skills-projects {
    padding: 40px 20px 40px 20px;
    /* Ajuste o padding lateral para 20px */
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 1200px;
    /* Define uma largura máxima */
    margin: 0;
    /* Remove margens */
    background-color: white;
    /* Fundo branco para a seção */
    padding: 40px 40px;
    /* Espaçamento interno */
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    /* Sombra para profundidade */
    border-radius: 8px;
    /* Cantos arredondados */
    padding-bottom: 300px;
    /* Margem superior */
  }
  .portfolio-container {
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    /* Layout flexível */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    /* Permite quebra de linha */
    justify-content: center;
    /* Centraliza os projetos */
    gap: 15px;
    /* Espaço entre os projetos */
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    /* Espaço abaixo da seção de projetos */
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  .title-portfolio-container {
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin-top: 130px;
    color: #2c3e50;
    text-align: center;
    /* Center align the portfolio title */
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    /* Increased space below the title */
  }
  .project {
    width: 100%;
    /* Largura total para responsividade */
    padding: 0 20px 10px 20px;
    max-width: 300px;
    /* Largura máxima para cada projeto */
    height: 200px;
    /* Altura fixa para uniformidade */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /* Oculta o excesso */
    border-radius: 12px;
    /* Cantos arredondados */
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    /* Sombra sutil */
    transition: transform 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
    /* Efeito de transição */
    text-decoration: none;
    /* Remove sublinhado */
    color: inherit;
    /* Herda a cor do pai */
    position: relative;
    /* Posicionamento relativo para sobreposição */
  }
  .project img {
    width: 100%;
    /* Full width for images */
    height: 100%;
    /* Full height for images */
    object-fit: cover;
    /* Cover to maintain aspect ratio */
    display: block;
    /* Block display to remove gaps */
  }
  /* FOOTER */
  .footer {
    height: 2vh;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    /* Posição absoluta */
    padding-top: 30px;
    /* Margem superior */
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .fale {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  .footer-form {
    margin: 0 30px 0 30px;
  }
  .footer-contact {
    text-align: center;
    /* Center-aligns text */
  }
  .contact-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* Stack items vertically */
    align-items: center;
    /* Center-align items */
    gap: 1px;
    /* Adjust the gap to bring them closer */
  }
  .contact-item {
    margin: 10px 0;
    /* Space between items */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    /* Align icon and text */
  }
  .contact-item i {
    margin-right: 10px;
    /* Space between icon and text */
  }
<!--This div has the skills container and the projects container-->
<div class="skills-projects">
  <!--The skills container-->
  <div id="skills" class="container-skills">
    <div class="skills">
      <h2 class="skills-title">Minhas Skills</h2>
      <ul>
        ...
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Projects container-->
  <div id="projects" class="container-projects">
    <div class="title-portfolio-container">
      <h2 class="display-4">Meus Projetos</h2>
      <p class="lead">Uma showcase do meu trabalho.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-container row">
      <a href="#modal-authp" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 project">
        <img src="{{ asset('images/projects/authp.png') }}" alt="Projeto 1" class="img-fluid">
        <div class="project-overlay">
          <span class="overlay-text">Abrir</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer id="contact" class="footer">
  <div class="fale">Fale comigo</div>
  <div class="footer-form">
    <form>
      <input name="name" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Nome(*)" />
      <input name="email" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Email(*)" />
      <input name="topico" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Tópico(*)" />
      <textarea name="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Sua mensagem(*)"></textarea>
      <button type="submit" class="submit-button">
                     Enviar <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="footer-contact" class="footer-contact">
    <div class="contact-container">
      <div class="contact-item">
        <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
        <span>xx xxxxx</span>
      </div>
      <div class="contact-item">
        <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
        <span>xx@xxx.com</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-copyright">
    &copy; Copyright 2024 xxx
  </div>
</footer>



screenshoot:[

Why is the footer positioned absolutely?
